# How do I debug an IIS FTP extension in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, iis-7

I have an IIS7 ftp extension developed in Visual Studio and successfully registered with the ftp service. How can I debug it so that I can attach to the ftp process (ftpsvc.dll) and break into the VS 2010 debugger?

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Windows Task Manager and switch to Services tab.
2. Find ftpsvc and check its PID.
3. Use Visual Studio to attach to this process.

Debug this process using your extension project in the usual way.